# How to handle session expired exception in Spring MVC-Spring Security app for GWT RPC calls

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, gwt-rpc

I have Spring MVC application where security is handled by Spring Security.

UI is built using GWT which gets the data from server using RPC approach.

I need to handle on UI the situation when session is expired:
For example RPC AsyncCallback can get SessionExpiredException type of exception and popup the window with message like "You session is expired, please click the refresh link" or something.

Did someone deal with such problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched a bit and uploaded the solution here http://code.google.com/p/gspring/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsample%2Fsession-expired%253Fstate%253Dclosed.

Use `mvn jetty:run-war` to see the demo after checking it out and go to `rpc-security-sample/index.htm`

**There are two ways to solve it**.

*The first* is around to pass the delegate proxy for GWT `RemoteServlet` which throws `SessionExpiredException` during method invocation. This requires to declare `Exception` in every RPC service method. Example: http://code.google.com/p/gspring/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsample%2Fsession-expired%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Steps:

1. Develop new filter which intercepts first
2. Declare `SessionExpiredException` in each RPC method service which could inherit `RuntimeException` for simplicity (no need to follow this in implementers)
3. Develop parent generic `AsyncCallback` handler
4. Use http://code.google.com/p/gspring/ solution to handle all incoming RCP requests.

*The second* which is much more simplest: return the 401 HTTP error and handle in UI side (GWT native general exception contains the HTTP status number). Example: http://code.google.com/p/gspring/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsample%2Fsession-expired-401

The second approach is simplest and does not require declaring Exception in service methods contract. However following the first approach can give you some flexibility: it could contain some additional info like last login time (for `SessionExpiredException`) etc. Also the second approach can introduce new exceptions which are inherited from `SecurityException` like blacklisted user (for example if user was blacklisted during his session) or for example if user does the same actions very often like a robot (it could be asked for passing the captcha) etc.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that for processing of incoming GWT call you use some Spring MVC controller or some servlet. It can have following logic

```
try{
    // decode payload from  GWT call
    com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(...)
    // get spring bean responsible for actual business logic
    Object bean = applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
    // execute business logic and encode response
    return RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(bean, ….)
} catch (com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException ex) {
    // send unexpected exception to client
    return RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(..., new MyCustomUnexpectedException(), …) ;
}
```

Solution for this case

```
HttpServletRequest request = getRequest() ; 
if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
    return RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(..., new MyCustomSessionExpiredException(), …) ;
} else {
    // first code snippet goes here
}
```

Then catch custom session expired exception in a client side code. If you do not use  RPC directly then provide more details about your bridge implementation between GWT and Spring.

You will need also force GWT compiler to include MyCustomSessionExpiredException type to a serialization white list (to prevent case when GWT security policy stops propogation of the exception to client side). Solution: include MyCustomSessionExpiredException type to each method signature of each synchronous interface:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("productRpcService.rpc")
public interface ProductRpcService extends RemoteService {
    List<Product> getAllProducts() throws ApplicationException;
    void removeProduct(Product product) throws ApplicationException;
}

MyCustomSessionExpiredException extends ApplicationException
```

Then show pop-up in client side code:

```
public class ApplicationUncaughtExceptionHandler implements GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override        
    public void onUncaughtException(Throwable caught) {
        if (caught instanceof MyCustomSessionExpiredException) {
            Window.alert("Session expired");
        }
    }
}

// Inside of EntryPoint.onModuleLoad method
GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ApplicationUncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge. Your approach is good but it mixes transport layers with business delegates one and uses internal GWT API which is not encouraged. Please see the demo in my answer which you can find in google code hosting. Thanks.