# Convert Spring Security AccessDeniedException ( with GWT )

Tags: gwt, spring-security

I'm using Google Web Toolkit and securing the server with spring security. I want to use the @PreAuthorize - annotation in my business object methods.

The problem here is, that the AccessDeniedException ( which is thrown if the user is not authorized to call this method ) is not Serializable by GWT. So i need to implement an additional try-catch in every RPC service method which calls the BO method transform the Exception by hand. I really want to avoid this additional try-catch!

Some more explanation:

BO ( secured with @PreAuthorize ) << is called by >> GWT RPC which need an additional try-catch to transform the exception.

All i've found is the mapper to map specific exceptions to specific pages but none information on how i can transform the exception to another one ( or provide my own implementation to throw my custom exception ).

I hope i could describe my problem in a way you guys can understand it.

I found this thread:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?85937-Method-Security-Throw-custom-exception-instead-of-AccessDeniedException

But the AccessDecisionManager only throws the AccessDeniedException and i can't get some advice on how to customize it for my needs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know any way to tell Spring Security use some another type instead of AccessDeniedException. So I think you need to place somewhere try/catch block and change exception type. There are multiple places to do it:

- You can override `MethodSecurityInterceptor` and then [configure Spring Security to use your class](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e5253). Here you can throw any exception type, so no problem with conversion. But I think it will be more difficult to do the conf.
- If you use solution where all incoming RPC calls pass trough one servlet / controller (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821984/how-to-handle-session-expired-exception-in-spring-mvc-spring-security-app-for-gw/13845837#13845837)) then you can apply conversion logic there.
- Maybe the most elegant solution is to apply custom AOP interceptor (that can do exception wrapping) for each necessary bean. This interceptor must implement `org.springframework.core.Ordered` interface and it can use `HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` constant to make sure that it will be executed before `MethodSecurityInterceptor`. See [this entry](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) for more details about ordering (it looks like the same Ordered interface is used for both cases: AspectJ and standard AOP). With `@Around("@annotation(org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize)")` you can apply your custom interceptor directly to PreAuthorize annotations, so no need for additional conf.

Comment: The incoming RPC calls are divided in several "logical modules" so i need to implement multiple try-catch scenarios which all will do the same. But the "afterInvocationManager" looks pretty good. Will try it and come back here later. Thanks!

Comment: You are wellcome. Maybe the most elegant solution is to apply custom AOP interceptor (that can do exception wrapping) for each necessary bean. By I do not know how to make sure that it will be executed before `MethodSecurityInterceptor `.

Comment: There is a way to define an order for AOP interceptors, so I updated my answer.

Comment: After searching around ( and read this one: http://www.denksoft.com/articles/acl-spring-security-tutorial/ ) it seems to be a lot of work and a huge overhead for simply trying to convert- or throw a different exception than the AccessDeniedException. Is it really necessary to implement all the steps by my own? I just wanted to implement a custom AfterInvocationProviderManager and catch the AccessDeniedException and throw a custom one. But when defining the bean for the ProviderManager i need to provide a list of providers. What can i do to tell spring to use the default ones?

Comment: From config file: '<bean id="myAccessDecisionManager" class="de.my.CustomAfterInvocationProviderManager" />' which brings the error: 'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A list of AfterInvocationProviders is required' . When providing an empty list its the same error.

Comment: Try to inject original AccessDecisionManager into your custom one and copy the content of the list.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with spring security... How can this be done?

Comment: I think `<bean id="myAccessDecisionManager" class="de.my.CustomAfterInvocationProviderManager" ><property name="originalAccessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager"/></bean>` must do the trick. I suppose that original access decision manager is registered with id `accessDecisionManager`. You can copy necessary collection directly in the setter. And if it works then you can find some more elegant solution (constructor dependency for example).

Comment: I really appreciate your help but i can't get it to work the way i want. With the AccessDecisionManager i only get notified on login ( Authentication ) and not on method security level ( Authorization ) and with the AfterInvocationProviderManager i do need a list of providers and with a sample provider i get another error. After hours of searching and trying i will quit this and try another approach. But thanks a bunch, sir!

Comment: Sorry, you need to replace AccessDecisionManager by AfterInvocationProviderManager in my previous comment: `<bean id="myAfterInvocationProviderManager" class="de.my.CustomAfterInvocationProviderManager" ><property name="originalAfterInvocationProviderManager" ref="afterInvocationManager"/></bean>`

Comment: This unfortunately also won't work. First error was undefined bean "afterInvocationManager" and if i try to define a bean with this name referencing the (ie) PostInvocationAdviceProvider i got an <init> error on this provider... Where do you have that "originalAfterInvocationProviderManager" from? I can't find this property somewhere else...

Comment: `<property name="originalAfterInvocationProviderManager" ref="afterInvocationManager"/>` snipped suppose that you already prepared `setOriginalAfterInvocationProviderManager(param of afterInvocationManager type)` in your `CustomAfterInvocationProviderManager` class. Strange that you do not have corresponding `afterInvocationManager`. It looks like it must be defined by default by Spring Security itself (see sample in official documentation). But I have not tried it by myself. Wich version of SS do you use?

Comment: Where did you get that mysterious setOriginalAfterInvocationProviderManager from? I can't find it in the documentation nor with google...?

Comment: It must be created by you in your `CustomAfterInvocationProviderManager` class. Are you familiar with dependency injection and spring's way to inject dependencies?

Comment: I'm afraid that my spring skills are not that much. But with your help and the MethodInterceptor tip i'm finally did it. I'll post my solution but will upvote your comments to give you reputation. Thanks again sir!

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it with the MethodInterceptor ( thanks goes to Maksym Demidas ). My solution looks like:

My custom MethodInterceptor which will wrap all calls and catch only the "GWT-non-serializable" AccessDeniedException to convert it to a standard Exception:

```
public class CustomInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation arg0) throws Throwable {

    try {
        System.out.println("********* INTERCEPT: "
                + arg0.getMethod().getName());
        return arg0.proceed();
    } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("AccessDeniedException for method: "
                + arg0.getMethod().getName());
        throw new Exception("Access denied!");
    }
}
```

And the important part from the applicationContext.xml:

```
    <!-- Define a bean with our custom MethodInterceptor -->
<bean id="debuglnterceptor" class="com.my.server.CustomInterceptor" />

<!-- Register our custom MethodInterceptor to wrap all methods called from 
    com.my.server.services classes -->
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="debuglnterceptor"
        pointcut="execution(* com.my.server.services..*(..))" />
</aop:config>
```

Comment: +1 for interceptor solution. Glad to see that it works for you. Two toughts on the shared code: 1) It may be more convinient to introduce some custom ClientAccessDeniedException and use it istead of Eception 2) may be it will be better to implement `org.springframework.core.Ordered` and ensure that your `CustomInterceptor` will be always fired **after** `MethodSecurityInterceptor`

Answer (score 1):

here's a development of [Maksim Demidas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677948/maksym-demidas)'s solution using Spring AOP:

Define a Spring AOP advice of type "throws advice". It implements interface Ordered with HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE for a correct integration with other advice such as `@Secured` or `@PreAuthorize`

```
public class AccessDeniedExceptionInterceptor implements ThrowsAdvice, Ordered {

    public void afterThrowing(AccessDeniedException e) throws GwtAccessDeniedException {

        throw new GwtAccessDeniedException();
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

In the Spring context file, define the interceptor as a bean:

```
<bean id="accessDeniedExceptionInterceptor" class="my.interceptor.package.AccessDeniedExceptionInterceptor"/>
```

In the Spring context file, configure the secured object. In this example, all public methods of a particular implementation are secured:

```
<!-- Configure global method security for the secured object -->
<security:global-method-security>
    <security:protect-pointcut access="ROLE_USER" 
            expression="execution(public * my.service.package.ServiceImpl.*(..))"/>
</security:global-method-security>
```

Define the service implementation bean:

```
<bean id="rpcServiceTarget" class="my.service.package.ServiceImpl"/>
```

Define a proxy for the service, and wire it to the interceptor:

```
<bean id="rpcService" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="my.service.package.Service"/>
    <property name="target" ref="rpcServiceTarget"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>accessDeniedExceptionInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And that's it. If you work with the proxy, you'll have the translation from Spring's AccessDeniedException to your custom GwtAccessDeniedException.